# clojure/java.jdbc and postgres: Prepared statments 100x slower than string concatenated queries?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, clojure

Are prepared statements supposed to be lots slower (100x) than just concatenating strings in JDBC?

#### Example:

This is very slow (selecting with 100 parameters):

```clj
(require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc])
(def db {:connection-uri "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/web_test?user=root"})

(time (count (jdbc/query db ["SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?;" 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1])))
"Elapsed time: 1182.672157 msecs"
```

This is fast:

```clj
(time (count (jdbc/query db ["SELECT 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1;"])))
"Elapsed time: 13.39071 msecs"
```

Both examples above are run against a local postgres. If I run against a remote postgres, things take about 10x longer still!

**Is this normal, and if not, how can I fix this so my code runs fast?**

The only clue I've manged to find is that if I turn on `log_duration = on` in my postgres configuration, I see lots of lines like this:

```
2019-10-10 16:00:29.546 BST [42818] LOG:  duration: 0.352 ms
2019-10-10 16:00:29.547 BST [42818] LOG:  duration: 0.386 ms
2019-10-10 16:00:29.548 BST [42818] LOG:  duration: 0.385 ms
2019-10-10 16:00:29.549 BST [42818] LOG:  duration: 0.384 ms
2019-10-10 16:00:29.550 BST [42818] LOG:  duration: 0.355 ms
... Repeats 100+ times
```

Running a prepared statment using `psql` is fast, so this is something related to how the jdbc driver works:

```
PREPARE query (integer,integer,....x100) AS
    SELECT $1, $2, $3, ....x100
;
EXECUTE inserter(1,1,1,1,1);

(runs in about 10ms)
```

#### What versions I'm on

Postgres 11 `(PostgreSQL 11.4 on x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0, compiled by Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4), 64-bit)`

with:

```
[org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.7.10"]
[org.postgresql/postgresql "42.2.8"]
```

#### Why I want to do this

The example above is not actually want to do, but a similar slowdown happens in my production code where I'm trying to insert data from a large CSV uploaded on a web service into a table. The insert takes like 2 mins for 10k rows, timing out the web request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the advice from Sean I managed to figure out the problem. The culpit was this bit of code that I use to convert strings into the postgres [EAN type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/isn.html). (Which I of course did not include in my question.. -_-)

```clj
(extend-protocol clojure.java.jdbc/ISQLParameter
  Object
  ; Check if this parameter is supposed to be a ean, and if so convert the incoming string to ean
  (set-parameter [val ^PreparedStatement stmt ^long i]
    (def sm stmt)
    ; PERFORMANCE KILLER LINE V --------------------------------
    (if (= (.getParameterTypeName (.getParameterMetaData stmt) i)
           "ean13")
      ; The type of this parameter should be PGObject, which is a wrapper provided by
      ; the postgres JDBC driver for types which does not have a corresponding type in
      ; the JDBC interface.
      (.setObject stmt i (doto (PGobject.)
                           (.setType "ean13")
                           (.setValue (str->ean13 val))))
      ; default behaviour
      (.setObject stmt i (jdbc/sql-value val)))))
```

The call to getParameterMetaData issued a call to the database to get the parameter type, causing one round trip to the DB per query parameter, leading to the crazy slowdown. Removing that bit of code solved the performance issue.

I have not figured out how to do that efficiently - worst case I'll have to just use a separate type in clojure for the EAN's insteads of having them just be strings in clojure, so that I can do something like 
`(extend-protocol clojure.java.jdbc/ISQLParameter Ean ...`

Answer (score 2):

Although I've commented a few times on Laurenz' answer with some suggestions -- and I've added some timing "tests" to `clojure.java.jdbc` to look at the performance of your two `SELECT`s with a variety of databases (including PostgreSQL) -- I have been unable to reproduce your results.

You mention `insert-multi!` and that reminded me that PostgreSQL does not send the inserts as a single batch unless you add `?rewriteBatchedInserts=true` to the JDBC URL (or use the `:dbtype`/`:dbname` hash map spec with `:rewriteBatchedInserts true` added in).

See [batch execution caveats](https://cljdoc.org/d/seancorfield/next.jdbc/1.0.8/doc/getting-started/prepared-statements#caveats) in the `next.jdbc` documentation (which will apply to c.j.j.'s `insert-multi!` as well). You might want to try [`next.jdbc`](https://github.com/seancorfield/next-jdbc) anyway since it is designed to be faster than c.j.j. (and use `execute-batch!` for your large inserts).

Answer (score 0):

I would expect the prepared statement in your example to be slower because the JDBC driver has more work to do. The time on the database should be the same.

Prepared statements offer a performance benefit only if they are reused. The JDBC driver uses server side prepared statements from the fifth execution on, and from the eleventh execution on PostgreSQL will use a generic plan. From then on the prepared statement should be faster.

Using that many columns is not a good design.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Laurenz, but surely not 100x slower? If I create and execute a prepared statment using psql the time for both solutions is about the same. 

I'm not using many columns, the example is just to illustrate the slowness of prepared statments in this case. The actual query I want to run looks something like this: ```insert into targets (name) values (?),(?),(?),(?)....```

Comment: Who knows with that many parameters. Try to profile where the time is spent. Does it change if you use the statement several times?

Comment: Queries like (jdbc/insert-multi) generates queries of this type when inserting rows - it in fact batches things up so that it's close to the maximum number of parameters allowed by postgres (32768 or so) - hence the reason for the question. The actual query takes a miniscule amount of time (when I've checked it with explain analyze). It looks like it's making as many round trips to the db as there are parameters, which seems like a bad idea but I don't know how to change that behaviour. I will clarify my question to mention that the problem gets worse when I'm querying a remote server.

Comment: No, it definitely won't make a round trip per parameter. This must be time spent in Java.

Comment: hmm but then why is it taking much longer when I run it against a remote sever? For example, the ```(time (count (jdbc/query prod-db ["SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?,``` call goes from 912ms with a local db, to 91763ms when I run against a remove db.

Comment: Ok, maybe I am wrong. I don't know what clojure does, I was anly talking about the JDBC driver. Perhaps you can set `log_min_duration_statement = 0` and see what actually arrives on the database end. Add that to the question, it will clarify the matter.

Comment: A couple of things I would suggest you try: first, time this (jdbc/with-db-connection [con db] (jdbc/query con ["..." ,,,])) -- to eliminate any overhead with having to create a connection inside the query function; second, if you can, try using the raw java.sql and javax.sql classes/Java interop instead of c.j.j. to eliminate any overhead in the Clojure library itself.

Comment: I've added a "test" to run these SELECT queries in the clojure.java.jdbc tests https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc/blob/master/src/test/clojure/clojure/java/jdbc_test.clj#L1257-L1271 -- Only when all functions in c.j.j. have instrumentation turned on is there a slowdown in the parameterized version.